# JS, show marker as string in google api using geojson

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm new with Javascript and i wonder how to show a marker as a value that loaded from geojson file. 
for example: a marker with the number 17.6396, where the coordinates is 35.04226 32.76994.
like in this map: http://www.meteo.co.il//MeteoMap.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script>
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: { lat: 32.7, lng: 35.1 },
zoom: 7,
  });


var script = document.createElement('script');
//data.json- this is the geojson
script.setAttribute('src',
'data.json');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});

// Defines the callback function referenced in the json file.
function temp_callback(data) {
map.data.addGeoJson(data);

}
</script>
</head>
<body id="map-container">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

data.json example:

```
temp_callback({
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
 {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates":  [ 35.02026,32.78685 ]
 },
"properties": {
"type":"Feature",
"id":1,
"weight":16.49633,
"geometry.type":"Point",
"time":"2015-03-24T14:55:00",
"coordinates":"35.02026 32.78685"
}
},
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates":  [ 35.04226,32.76994 ]
},
"properties": {
"type":"Feature",
"id":2,
"weight":17.6396,
"geometry.type":"Point",
"time":"2015-03-24T14:50:00",
"coordinates":"35.04226 32.76994"
}
}
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add numbers on custom markers using the following tutorial:

[**Link**](http://biostall.com/adding-number-or-letters-to-google-maps-api-markers)

and after that attach infowindow to each custom marker:

[**Link**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

Comment: yes, but i want to have a dynamic numbers that change every update of the json file. any idea?

Comment: So you are getting the number from your json file, no? Every time you update the json file, retrieve the value for "weight" and there are a lot of ways of updating the marker image: (a function that deletes and load new marker when json is received, a variable that updates when new json received, etc). Be creative :).